# Restart animation on state/props change in react-motion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-motion

I am trying to animate breadcrumbs using react-motion from `x: -20` to `x: 0`.

`Folder > SubFolder > Child`

The issue is, the breadcrumbs animate perfectly on the first render. Subsequently when the `props` or even `state` changes, the animations are not updated. This seems to be a [known bug](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion/issues/322).

My question is, how do I "restart" animation on state/prop changes?

```
const getDefaultStyles = crumbs => {
  const defaultStyles = crumbs.map(() => ({x: -20}))
  console.log(defaultStyles)
  return defaultStyles
}

const getStyles = previousInterpolatedStyles => {
  return previousInterpolatedStyles.map((_, i) => {
    return i === 0 ? {x: spring(0)} : {x: spring(previousInterpolatedStyles[i-1].x)}
  })
}

const Breadcrumb = ({ crumbs }) => (
  <div className='breadcrumb-container'>

      <StaggeredMotion
        defaultStyles={getDefaultStyles(crumbs)}
        styles={getStyles}>
        {
          interpolatedStyles =>
            <div className='breadcrumb-list'>
              {
                interpolatedStyles.map(({x}, i) =>
                  <div className='breadcrumb' key={i} style={{
                      WebkitTransform: `translate3d(${x}px, 0, 0)`,
                      transform: `translate3d(${x}px, 0, 0)`
                    }}>
                    <a href='#'>Title</a>                    
                  </div>
                )
              }
            </div>

        }
      </StaggeredMotion>

  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Going through the `react-motion`, I've found a fix by setting a unique `key` prop in `Motion`, `StaggeredMotion` causes it to re-render on state change.

Refer [this issue](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion/issues/259) on the official repo.

For my case I solved it by setting the `key` prop to the length of the breadcrumb list.

```
<StaggeredMotion
      key={this.props.crumbs.length}
      ...>
    ...
</StaggeredMotion>
```

Comment: This also solved my issue for re-animating a flash message. First render was always fine but upon rerender, animation did not get reset. Setting `key` prop to `Date.now()` solved my issue since I always want to re-animate when a new flash msg appears.